# I'm trying to understand indexOf

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I found this code on w3 schools when I was looking to figure out how to put a search bar in my dropdown box in my website. I cannot however understand how the code works at all. Everytime I think I get close to understanding it I get confused

```
function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
   }
}
```

So I understand that "a" is a list of all my elements and that it the first one has a value of 0 then 1, 2, 3, etc. I don't understand how I retrieve the text that I'm putting in the box and how it gets filtered. So in the txtValue string its changing the text to uppercase but how is it getting the text, and then how does it know what to filter. Also I'm very confused about the -1.
If anyone could help me understand I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: No, your understanding is wrong. `<a>` elements do not have a "value"; the code you posted is looking at the text content of the tags. The code is looking for `<a>` elements whose content match (at least partially) the value of the "myInput" input field. The ones that match are left showing, the ones that don't are hidden.

Comment: Here is a good place to learn more about this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Functionality of your code**

The code you've posted loops over the elements in `a` and checks whether each element's text content (either `textContent` or `innerText`) contains the given `filter` value as a substring. The value of `filter` comes from the input element `filter`. If the element's text does contain `filter` as a substring, the CSS display value of the element is set to `""` (default), otherwise the element is hidden by setting its CSS display value to `"none"`.

For example if you have the a elements:

```
<a href="http://a.com">Great Site</a>
<a href="http://b.com">Okay Site</a>
<a href="http://c.com">Great Website</a>
```

And entered `"great"` in to the filter input. The first and last elements would have their CSS display properties set to `""` and would therefore remain visible. While the middle element would have its display set to `"none"` and would become hidden.

**indexOf**

The `indexOf` method in JavaScript returns the index of the first occurrence of the given element in an array or string. For example `'abcb'.indexOf('b')` returns `1`. If the element is not found in the array, `indexOf` returns `-1`.

So the line:

```
if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
```

really just checks if `filter` is a substring of `txtValue`.

A more straightforward way of getting the same functionality would be to use the `includes` method. For example:

```
if (txtValue.toUpperCase().includes(filter)) {
```

Note also that the call of `toUpperCase` is only done to perform the substring search in a case-insensitive way, so that `"Hello"` would match `"hEllo"`.

Answer (score 0):

> but how is it getting the text

```
txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText
```

This will get the text from the current item in the outer loop. The loop essentially goes through all elements in your dropdown list. Note that if textContent is empty, it will use the innerText attribute.

> and then how does it know what to filter

```
if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)
```

In this line, the value of filter is the search string (capitalized). The value of txtValue.toUpperCase() is the text value from above (capitalized).

Here is what the function indexOf() does taken from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp):

> The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.
>
> This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.
>
> Note: The indexOf() method is case sensitive.
>
> Tip: Also look at the lastIndexOf() method.

So essentially, you are searching for the value of filter inside txtValue, and if not found, it will hide the item from the list.

Answer (score 0):

In the above code variable `a` holds all anchor tag elements in the document (`<a>...</a>`). As variable `a` is an array and in javascript, values from an array can be accessed using indices starting from 0.

We are iterating the array using for loop and in each iteration we access

```js
txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
```

txtValue by accessing the array `a` and check for a match using string function `indexOf`. If a match is found it gives the position of the index of the match ( >= 0) in the string, -1 otherwise